# Compress a sparse matrix

Tags: code-golf, number, array, matrix

Compress a sparse matrix using [Compressed sparse row (CSR, CRS or Yale format)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_.28CSR.2C_CRS_or_Yale_format.29).

These are all the same form of compression (ignore new Yale).

Input may be any 2d data structure (list of lists, etc): e.g

```
[[0 0 0 0],
 [5 8 0 0],
 [0 0 3 0],
 [0 6 0 0]]
```

And the output should be three 1d data structures (list etc), that denote the outputs `A`, `IA` and `JA`, for example

```
[5, 8, 3, 6]
[0, 0, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 1,]
```

The process is described by wikipedia:

> - The array `A` is of length `NNZ` and holds all the nonzero entries of `M` in
>   left-to-right top-to-bottom ("row-major") order.
> - The array `IA` is of length `m + 1`. It is defined by this recursive
>   definition:
> - `IA[0] = 0`
>
>   `IA[i] = IA[i − 1] + (number of nonzero elements on the (i − 1)-th row in the original matrix)`
> - Thus, the first `m` elements of `IA` store the index into `A` of the first
>   nonzero element in each row of `M`, and the last element `IA[m]` stores
>   `NNZ`, the number of elements in `A`, which can be also thought of as the
>   index in `A` of first element of a phantom row just beyond the end of
>   the matrix `M`. The values of the `i`-th row of the original matrix is
>   read from the elements `A[IA[i]]` to `A[IA[i + 1] − 1]` (inclusive on both
>   ends), i.e. from the start of one row to the last index just before
>   the start of the next.[5]
> - The third array, `JA`, contains the column index in `M` of each element of
>   `A` and hence is of length `NNZ` as well.

If your language doesn't support actual data structures, input and output may be text.

## Test cases

Input 1:

```
[[0 0 0 0],
 [5 8 0 0],
 [0 0 3 0],
 [0 6 0 0]]
```

Output 1:

```
[ 5, 8, 3, 6 ]
[ 0, 0, 2, 3, 4 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 1, ]
```

Input 2

```
[[10 20 0 0 0 0],
 [0 30 0 40 0 0],
 [0 0 50 60 70 0],
 [0 0 0 0 0 80]]
```

Output 2:

```
[ 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 ]
[  0  2  4  7  8 ]
[  0  1  1  3  2  3  4  5 ]
```

Input 3:

```
[[0 0 0],
 [0 0 0],
 [0 0 0]]
```

Output 3:

```
[ ]
[ 0 0 0 0 ]
[ ]
```

Input 4:

```
[[1 1 1],
 [1 1 1],
 [1 1 1]]
```

Output 4:

```
[ 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ]
[ 0 3 6 9 ]
[ 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 ]
```

Input 5:

```
[[0 0 0 0],
 [5 -9 0 0],
 [0 0 0.3 0],
 [0 -400 0 0]]
```

Output 5:

```
[ 5, -9, 0.3, -400 ]
[ 0, 0, 2, 3, 4 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 1, ]
```

Assume inputs may contain any real number, you need not consider mathematical symbols or exponential representation (e.g. 5,000 will never be entered as 5e3). You will not need to handle `inf`, `-inf`, `NaN` or any other 'pseudo-numbers'. You may output a different representation of the number (5,000 *may* be output as 5e3 if you so choose).

## Scoring

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), fewest bytes wins.

Comment: Could 1-based indices be used for the last row?

Comment: @Leo for JA? No.

Comment: Isn't `IA[0] = 0` completely unnecessary? It's only needed to define `IA[i] = IA[i − 1]...`, yet we could simply state that if `i-1 < 0` to use 0. That is, IA[0] is *always* equal to 0, therefor it can be compressed out (yes, I realize that this is a critique of the algorithm, not this challenge).

Comment: Will we have the inverse challenge too?

Comment: @Draco18s I beleive that's what distinguishes Yale and new Yale formats.

Comment: @Adám I would like to think so

Comment: Neat! Hadn't run into either format before, but I'm glad to see someone else did see that before (I shouldn't be the kind of person who spots trivial optimizations in algorithms this old).

Comment: Is this going to get the inverse challenge 3 years later?

Comment: @Giuseppe I still haven't gotten round to it, sorry 'bout that

Comment: @Adám someone has made a [sandbox post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/22116#22116)  for the reverse challenge

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 19 bytes

```
!3#f!Dx0Gg!XsYshDq!
```

Input uses `;` as row separator.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X9FYOU3RpcLAPV0xojiyOMOlUPH//2gDBTC0VjBVsIAwQHxjCMMMxIkFAA) Or verify all test cases: [1](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X9FYOU3RpcLAPV0xojiyOMOlUPH//2gDBTC0VjBVsIAwQHxjCMMMxIkFAA), [2](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X9FYOU3RpcLAPV0xojiyOMOlUPH//2hDAwUjAwUotAYSxiCWCZxroGBqoGBmoGAO50OghUEsAA), [3](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X9FYOU3RpcLAPV0xojiyOMOlUPH//2gDBSC0VkCmYgE), [4](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X9FYOU3RpcLAPV0xojiyOMOlUPH//2hDBSC0VkCmYgE), [5](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X9FYOU3RpcLAPV0xojiyOMOlUPH//2gDBTC0VjBV0LWEsMACesYQpq6JAZgfCwA).

#### Explanation

```
!     % Implicit input. Transpose
3#f   % 3-output version of find: it takes all nonzero values and pushes
      % their column indices, row indices, and values, as column vectors
!     % Transpose into a row vector
D     % Display (and pop) vector of values
x     % Delete vector of row values
0     % Push 0
G     % Push input
g     % Convert to logical: nonzeros become 1
!     % Transpose
Xs    % Sum of columns. Gives a row vector
Ys    % Cumulative sum
h     % Prepend the 0 that's below on the stack
D     % Display (and pop) that vector
q     % Subtract 1 from the vector of row indices
!     % Transpose into a row vector. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 78 bytes

```
{a=SparseArray@#;a@"NonzeroValues",a@"RowPointers",Join@@a@"ColumnIndices"-1}&
```

See [this answer on mathematica.stackexchange.com](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83722/6652).

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>31</s> 28 chars or <s>36</s> 33 bytes*

Requires `⎕IO←0` for zero based indexing. I/O is list of lists.

```apl
{(∊d)(0,+\≢¨d←⍵~¨0)(∊⍸¨⍵≠0)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/9OAZLXGo46uFE0NAx3tmEediw6tSAEKPurdWndohYEmSO5R745DK4ACjzoXGGjW/g8qzQPpUldQf9S76lEvUKYTyNB41DYRqEZTXeFR2yR1DZBU31SvYH@/QyvSFEAStUByroJXaXGJQlp@kUJeZnKqQkpmcUFOYiXISAUNAwUw1FTQMFWwgLJAIsZQlhlYjAus1tBAwQiqHiprDGKaGCDpMwVqMVAwRwhAoAXMDGS1CBpqvgIQaqLTXBjuPLTeElm3Hsyth9abGEBUAQA)

`{`…`}` anonymous function where the argument is represented by *⍵*

`(`…`)(`…`)(`…`)` return a list of three things:

`⍵≠0` Boolean where the argument differs from 0
  `⍸¨` **ɩ**ndices of those for each sub-list
  `∊` **ϵ**nlist (flatten) to combine into single list

`⍵~¨0` remove zeros from each sub-list of the argument
  `d←` store that as *d*
  `≢¨` tally each
  `+\` cumulative sum
  `0,` prepend a zero

`∊d` **ϵ**nlist (flatten) *d* to combine into single list

---

<sup>* To run in Dyalog Classic, simply replace `⍸` with `⎕U2378`.</sup>

Comment: Nice, I don't understand the input format though? `f 4 4⍴` and then the values?

Comment: @Pureferret the Code defines the function `f`. The Input is really a REPL, which calls `f` on the result of `4 4⍴…` which **r**eshapes the data into a 4×4 matrix.

Comment: Rho for **r**eshapes. I get it!

Comment: @Pureferret I've updated the *Try it online!* link to better show test cases.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 24 bytes

```
n0S€0;;\S€,T€Ẏ$’$
Ẏḟ0W;Ç
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/PIPhR0xoDa@sYEK0TAiQe7upTedQwU4ULyHi4Y75BuPXh9v///0dHG@goQFGsDpdCtKmOggUSFyJljMQ1g8rGAgA)

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 87 bytes

```
f s|a<-filter(/=0)<$>s=(id=<<a,scanl(+)0$length<$>a,s>>= \t->[i|(i,e)<-zip[0..]t,e/=0])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYyxDsIgEIZ3n@KGDhChkhiNA/AiyEAstRcRm8Jk@u6IDYmLueG@fP/dP7n08CGUMkJaneQjhuwXclCCyk4nRXBQUjqWbi4GsqeiCz7e81TDKrVWcM1cG1wJMk8lf@NsRN/bzHztsLQ8HUZQMLx2APOCMUMHIxgj2DaWmRO7NPqaY6Pz5uy/r3b52xbKBw)

How it works:

```
a<-filter(/=0)<$>s           -- let a be the list of lists with all 0 removed]
                             -- e.g. [[1,0,0],[0,3,4]] -> [[1],[3,4]]

                             -- return a triple of

id=<<a                       -- a concatenated into a single list -> A 

scanl(+)0$length<$>a         -- partial sums of the length of the sublists of a
                             -- strating with an additional 0 -> IA

s>>=                         -- map the lambda over the sublists of s and concatenate
                             -- into a single list
   \t->[i|(i,e)<-zip[0..]t,e/=0]  -- the indices of the non-zero elements -> JA
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python+SciPy, 79 bytes

<sub>i guess built-ins were not forbidden</sub>

```python
from scipy.sparse import*
A=csr_matrix(input())
print A.data,A.indptr,A.indices
```

Accepts input in the format `[[0, 0, 0, 0],[5, 8, 0, 0],[0, 0, 3, 0],[0, 6, 0, 0]]`

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 70 bytes

```r
function(m,M=t(m))list(M[x<-!!M],diffinv(colSums(x)),which(x,T)[,1]-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYzNCoMwEIRfRW@7sIFKf@hBHyGnehMPNiW4YDYQY02fPmpLGfjmm8uEbItaFdkuYiJ7AUe6ieAQJ54j6C7Vqix1Ty@2luUNxk@Pxc2QEGkd2YyQqMWOql5VmC24IQZOYOBEv1zpTn8/f3k7iCTBr82FZH/c6/k5ZouYNw)

This is an old, [matrix](/questions/tagged/matrix) challenge that didn't get an R answer for 3 years! Having to do this in row-major rather than column-major order costs 8 bytes (`,M=t(m))`).

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 96 bytes

```python
lambda m:list(map(list,zip(*[[e,i,j] for i,r in enumerate(m) for j,e in enumerate(r) if e!=0])))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7LCsIwEEX3/Yq4S2QqYx@@oF8Ss4iYYEqThhgX@vO1L4hyGbj3MHMZ/46P3pWDbq5DJ@3tLom9dOYZqZWeTgY@xtMt5woMtILoPhAD4zii3MuqIKOils28BfXPAyNGE7VpUDDGhliQhnC@RygQVgngCOVkq5QRaoQDwjGBRScUIov1XJMKasjPP7e4K1efV7jsiMwH4yLVNBaMpVCPX30B)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>31</s> <s>27</s> 17 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Hopefully this output format is OK.

```
cf pUmè iT å+ Ucð
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=Y2YgcFVt6CBpVCDlKyBVY/A&input=WwpbMCAwIDAgMF0KWzUgOCAwIDBdClswIDAgMyAwXQpbMCA2IDAgMF0KXS1R)

```
cf pUmè iT å+ Ucð     :Implicit input of 2D array U
c                     :Flat map
 f                    :  Filter
   p                  :Push the following two elements
    Um                :  First element: Map U
      è               :    Count the truthy elements in each
        i             :  Prepend
         T            :    Zero
           å+         :  Cumulatively reduce by addition
              Uc      :  Second element: Flat map U
                ð     :    0-based indices of truthy elements
```

Comment: I just ran the other examples though and it works

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 107 bytes

```php
<?for($y=[$c=0];$r=$_GET[+$l++];)foreach($r as$k=>$v)!$v?:[$x[]=$v,$z[]=$k,$y[$l]=++$c];var_dump($x,$y,$z);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY1BCsIwFET3nkLLLFqSRUEUMX67Ei/g7vMppSqFthgihtbLxyiIdjHMMG9gbGPDrrCNnaE8Hk7EnOSJ/pNoTlYxbSbNly8nzfq3EROuN5diJEZNuRg4@jywQqeUmCziS1U3Kdy8uqOlPXy2gC@2jIGF4DWeb281RkYnpBRqMb5y5fnR2xRDBHGTmRBe)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 109 bytes

```php
<?$y=[$c=0];foreach($_GET as$r){foreach($r as$k=>$v)if($v){$x[]=$v;$z[]=$k;$c++;}$y[]=$c;}var_dump($x,$y,$z);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKUS7@4aYhsdrWSgpIOEY3WilUyBLAsUEZi8MYqIGUJNrPV/lUrbaJVkW4NY67T8otTE5AwNsBUKicUqRZrVcLEikEC2rZ1KmWZmmgaQrFapiI61VSmzVqkC0dnWKsna2ta1KpUgXrJ1bVliUXxKaW6BhkqFjkqljkqVpvX//wA)

Comment: Does this need the numbers to be strings?

Comment: @Pureferret Any Input in PHP is a string or an array of strings. I have not casted the input so if you wish that the output is purely int  replace `$x[]=$v`  with `$x[]=+$v`

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 117 bytes

```js
a=>[a.map((b,i)=>(b=b.filter((x,c)=>x&&o.push(c)),m[i+1]=m[i]+b.length,b),m=[0],o=[]).reduce((x,y)=>x.concat(y)),m,o]
```

Input is a 2D array of numbers and output is an array of `[A, IA, JA]`.

### Explained

```js
a=>[
    a.map((b,i) => (                                // map each matrix row
            b = b.filter((x,c) => x                 // filter to only non-zero elements
                && o.push(c)                        // and add this index to JA
            )
            m[i+1] = m[i] + b.length,               // set next value of IA
            b                                       // and return filtered row
        ),
        m=[0],o=[]                          // initialize IA (m) and JA (o)
    ).reduce((x,y) => x.concat(y)),                 // flatten the non-zero matrix
m,o]                                                // append IA and JA
```

### Tests

```js
let f=
a=>[a.map((b,i)=>(b=b.filter((x,c)=>x&&o.push(c)),m[i+1]=m[i]+b.length,b),m=[0],o=[]).reduce((x,y)=>x.concat(y)),m,o]

let run=x=>O.innerHTML+=f(x).map(s=>`[${s.join`, `}]`).join`\n`+"\n\n"
run([[0,0,0,0],[5,8,0,0],[0,0,3,0],[0,6,0,0]])
run([[10,20,0,0,0,0],[0,30,0,40,0,0],[0,0,50,60,70,0],[0,0,0,0,0,80]])
run([[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]])
run([[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]])
run([[0,0,0,0],[5,-9,0,0],[0,0,0.3,0],[0,-400,0,0]])
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 115 bytes

```python
lambda m:zip(*[[v,i]for k in m for i,v in enumerate(k)if v])+[reduce(lambda a,b:a+[len(b)-b.count(0)+a[-1]],m,[0])]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzLDoIwEEX3fsUsWxnIiOIr8UvqLAqU2EALIYVEfx5FSTB3c@48TvcMj9anU3W7T412eanBXV@2E1ulRrRctT3UYD04mNHiOBfjB2d6HYyopa1gZBmp3pRDYcQi0ZhfdaQa40Uu4zwp2sEHQTLSKt4xo0NFLHkKKdxAqR1hSriEPzvcz3hYO2FGeCQ8rYNfzsS8CdlXswoyjC9/v5TsF44P9LvhTddbH6ASIZUrZ3J6Aw)

Output is `[A, JA, IA]`

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 84 bytes

```
{.flatmap(*.grep(+*)),(0,|[\+] .map(+*.grep(+*))),.flat.kv.flatmap:{$^a%.[0]xx?$^b}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYvtCoIwGIVv5fww2dwYbx9apNmFmMIC148UhkYo5rUv7APG8@fwPBxbd03i2hGhwclNyjT60WrLInXrastExLlkJF/FRZRQSxFe4vJzUPfn/3icgkqvVEHlMJyD6jrPLkWvRxjGsjVhQ/iRS2SE7bJ3niDEhISw98yXA@Wcp@4N)

The single matrix argument is in `$_`.

- `.flatmap(*.grep(+*))` selects the nonzero elements of the entire matrix.
- `[\+] .map(+*.grep(+*))` is the triangular reduction of the number of elements in each row (which some languages call `scan`).  `(0,|...)` prepends a zero to that list.
- `.flat.kv` produces an indexed list of all elements of the matrix.  `.flatmap: { $^a % .[0] xx ?$^b }` flat-maps over the modulus of each index by the number of columns in the array (`.[0]`, the number of elements in the first row), replicated by the element itself, interpreted as a boolean.  That is, nonzero elements are replicated once, and zero elements are replicated zero times (ie, removed).

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), <sup><s>66</s></sup> 63 bytes

```
using SparseArrays
n*a=getfield(sparse(a'),n)
!a=5a,3a.-1,4a.-1
```

`SparseArrays` is a standard library that stores with CSC instead of CSR (column instead of row or something), that's why we need to transpose (`a'`).

-6 bytes if 1-indexing was allowed

overloads `*` with `getfield` to save a few bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVHLboMwELz7Kza5FFfGsmNo4MCh39Aj5WAlTuQKOYhHlXw99QMotD3Ua63WM@udtfdjqLXk93EcOm2u8NbItlOvbSsfHTLPsriq/qJVfY46z0TyCROD0U4WqSRC0piTxPnxMphTr28GetX1kTYE1L2hlGIEdt2GHgrYaeNPZ901tXzYrMA2rTZ9baL9u9lvEBrZi9scX6mAT3WikVXAWxYjZc4I@R5QWTLwViEoU8jm0GFiDl88WhFUQkogIyCIxfyZEbcPHkoWiHvI@grhRYgzOExic2Hh4oStRVMrx@C4QoJlUwOhivDXltyMBWmbBwewjcAR7FsWjPstPCk8nzoSbz9hEfwOfIXwqskCsnqVrczdhR@BzXPd/rKpmLAfmM8Hbvta@wr/PZ0433RHlwHFCWObGcU5cTwJzL8mhccv)

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 82 bytes

```scala
x=>x.flatMap(_.zipWithIndex).filter(_._1!=0).unzip->x.scanLeft(0)(_+_.count(_!=0))
```

[Try it in Scastie!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/bOf3LO1ERQSNkIt1fl43Zg)

Returns `((A, JA), IA)`

Explanation:

```scala
x =>     //The sparse matrix to be smooshed
x.flatMap(      //Do the following operation to each row, then flatten the result
  _.zipWithIndex //Zip each element with its column (makes tuples)
).filter(      //Keep the tuples where
  _._1!=0      //the first element isn't 0
).unzip        //Unzip into a tuple of two lists, A and JA
->             //Make that the first element of another 2-tuple with IA:
x.scanLeft(0)(  //Starting with 0
  _+_.count(_!=0)  //Add the number of nonzero elements in each row
)               //Keep the intermediate results, giving us IA
```